# how to get session value inside symfony2 i use fosuserbundle

Tags: php, symfony, session, request, fosuserbundle

i'm using fosuserbundle and this is my function inside FOSUBUserProvider class :

```
public function connect(UserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response)
    {

      // and here i want to get session value like:
       $session = $request->getSession();
       $session->get('value1');
     //
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to inject Session in your Services Declaration,

and then add it in constructor of `FOSUserProvider` class,

in `services.yml`  and services section add `@session`

```
parameters:
    my_user_provider.class: Auth\UserBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider

services:
    my_user_provider:
        class: "%my_user_provider.class%"
        #this is the place where the properties are passed to the UserProvider class
        arguments: [@fos_user.user_manager,{facebook: facebookID},@session,@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

declare `$session` and $em variable in your class above `connect` function and add following constructor,

```
public function __construct(UserManager $userManager, Array $properties, Session $session, EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->session=$session;
        $this->em=$em;
        parent::__construct($userManager, $properties);
    }
```

in function `Connect` you can get it as,

```
public function connect(UserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
       $value=$this->session->get('value1');
       $em=$this->em;  // or directly use $this->em->flush(); or whatever you want
     . 
     .
     .
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer i do that but how to get the $session inside connect function

Comment: if you have done above things then you can get it as `$value = $this->session->get('value1');`

Comment: Thank uuuuuuu so mush you made my day :D

Comment: do you know how to use $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); inside this function