# use $getDoctrine() inside FOSUBUserProvider class :

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, response

```
public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

}
```

I then get the following error message:

> Error method getDoctrine() not found inside FOSUBUserProvider

Comment: What class is it in? Is it a service?

Comment: look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226728/how-to-get-session-value-inside-symfony2-i-use-fosuserbundle

Answer (score 0):

your.service_id:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Timesheet
    arguments: [@doctrine]

private $doctrine;

```
/**
 * @param Registry $doctrine Doctrine
 */
public function __construct(Registry $doctrine)
{
    $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
}

public function yourMethod()
{
  $this->doctrine->getRepository('UtilisateurBundle:compte')->find('1');
}
```